# Objects.requireNonNull problem with my dialogflow chatbot app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, chatbot

That's the error:

[image]

The application is an interface with a dialogflow chatbot. The application is crushing when i set some text and i try to send it. Probably its because there is some depracated code, but i cant find a solution on the internet.

BTW that's the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BotReply {

RecyclerView chatView;
ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editMessage;
Button btnSend;

//dialogFlow
private SessionsClient sessionsClient;
private SessionName sessionName;
private final String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chatView = findViewById(R.id.rv_message);
    editMessage = findViewById(R.id.et_message);
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btn_mic);

    chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(messageList, this);
    chatView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            String message = editMessage.getText().toString();
            if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                messageList.add(new Message(message, false));
                editMessage.setText("");
                sendMessageToBot(message);
                Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getLayoutManager())
                        .scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter text!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    setUpBot();
}

private void setUpBot() {
    String TAG = "mainactivity";
    try {
        InputStream stream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
                .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials) credentials).getProjectId();

        SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
        SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();
        sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
        sessionName = SessionName.of(projectId, uuid);

        Log.d(TAG, "projectId : " + projectId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUpBot: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}



private void sendMessageToBot(String message) {
    QueryInput input = QueryInput.newBuilder()
            .setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(message).setLanguageCode("en-US")).build();
    new SendMessageInBg(this, sessionName, sessionsClient, input).execute();
}



@Override
public void callback(DetectIntentResponse returnResponse) {
    if(returnResponse!=null) {
        String botReply = returnResponse.getQueryResult().getFulfillmentText();
        if(!botReply.isEmpty()){
            messageList.add(new Message(botReply, true));
            chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "failed to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

I think the problem is here:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
Objects.requireNonNull(chatView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
```

If you need something else ask! Thanks

Comment: Seems like `chatView.getAdapter()` or `chatView.getLayoutManager` returns null. You should only use `Objects.requireNonNull` if you are sure that the parameter is not null (or you are building an API and the variable is non-null by the API contract).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `messageList` is empty by default (and looks like it is) you have an empty recycler view and thus there are no non-fatal errors in the logs informing you that the recycler view is missing a layout manager. Set the layout manager to your `chatView` recycler view and it should be enough.

```
...
chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(messageList, this);
chatView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

// Add these two lines
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
chatView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...
```